# Moving a tsv file from local file system to S3 in luigi

Tags: python, amazon-s3, csv, luigi

The following program does not output anything, nor does it throw any errors. Am I missing something in form of the `run()` method in the `to_S3()` class?

```
class to_S3(luigi.Task):

    #The class Mysql_to_tsv converts the data returned by a query on a Mysqldb and stores the data in a tsv in a local file.

    def requires(self):
        return [Mysql_to_tsv]

    def output(self):
        return luigi.S3Target("https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/luigi_attempt.tsv")
```

The `output()` method of the `Mysql_to_tsv()` class is:

```
def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('/Users/user/Desktop/Work/Luigi/test_data.tsv')
```

Please help with the correct class implementation of the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I originally wanted put some data into an S3 bucket.

So, one does not need an `output()` method to have run a particular task (Ex: dumping of data to an S3 bucket.)

It can be done directly in the `run()` method, and the `output()` can be used to check for a flag or existence.

So, the correct implementation would be:

```
class to_S3(luigi.Task):

    def requires(self):
        return [Mysql_to_csv()]


    def run(self):

        #Creating a connection
        access_key = ""
        access_secret = ""
        conn = S3Connection(access_key, access_secret)

        #Connecting to the bucket
        bucket_name = ""
        bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)

        #Setting up the keys
        k = Key(bucket)
        k.key = "sample1"
        k.set_contents_from_filename("../test_data.tsv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all non-external luigi tasks needs a `run()` method.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I would like to know what would go into the run method, as I have already included the `requires()` method and the `output()` method as an S3 target, along with the S3 bucket location.

PS: The task returned by the `requires()` method stores a tsv file in local. (mentioned in the question)